# Tag template instead of 'post' in the following loop

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, taxonomy

I'm using the code (loop) below for the blog post grid displaying. I want the following structure for my tag.php as well (the post by the tag instead of all blog posts). But I don't know how to do it. Could you, please, check it?

I can't remember how I solved the following problem in the past but I'm at a 100% sure that I found the solution previously.

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { // 'page' is used instead of 'paged' on Static Front Page
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

$custom_query_args = array(
    'taxonomy_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    //'category_name' => 'custom-cat',
    'order' => 'DESC', // 'ASC'
    'orderby' => 'date' // modified | title | name | ID | rand
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>


<div class="item col-sm-4">
<div class="well">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<span class="date"><?php echo get_the_date("j.n.Y"); ?></span>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
}
?></a>

<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<div class="readmore-wrapper">
    <a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Suite</a>
</div>
</div></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
<?php if ($custom_query->max_num_pages > 1) : // custom pagination  ?>
        <?php
        $orig_query = $wp_query; // fix for pagination to work
        $wp_query = $custom_query;
        ?>
        <nav class="prev-next-posts">
                       <div class="next-posts-link">
                <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( '&lt; Page précédente' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="prev-posts-link">
                <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Page suivante &gt;', $custom_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
            </div>

        </nav>
        <?php
        $wp_query = $orig_query; // fix for pagination to work
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php
    wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query 
else:
    echo '<p>'.__('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.').'</p>';
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check WP_Query with Tag Parameter 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters
example:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
    'taxonomy_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    //'category_name' => 'custom-cat',
    'order' => 'DESC', // 'ASC'
    'orderby' => 'date', // modified | title | name | ID | rand
    'tag' => 'tag1,tag2' 
);
```